# Hybrid docker swarm setup with Windows host + Linux vm

Tags: docker, swarm

Is it possible to create swarm with the following nodes setup:

- Host machine(docker desktop in Windows containers mode)- Manager, Worker
- VM on HyperV, same machine- Worker

I tried following:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr 172.18.69.65
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch ‘Default Switch’ --hyperv-disable-dynamic-memory --hyperv-memory 2048 --hyperv-boot2docker-url https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v19.03.2/boot2docker.iso docker-worker-linux
docker-machine ssh docker-worker-linux
docker@docker-worker-linux:~$ ping 172.18.69.65
PING 172.18.69.65 (172.18.69.65): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.69.65: seq=0 ttl=128 time=0.294 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.69.65: seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.264 ms
docker@docker-worker-linux:~ docker swarm join --token bla-bla-bla 172.18.69.65:2377 Error response from daemon: Timeout was reached before node joined. The attempt to join the swarm will continue in the background. Use the "docker info" command to see the current swarm status of your node. 
docker@docker-worker-linux:~ docker info
Swarm: error
NodeID:
Error: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
Is Manager: false
Node Address: 172.18.69.66
```

Should it be possible at all- joining host windows machine running docker desktop with linux vm as swarm nodes?